# How can a session variable be read in a Spring annotation expression, specifically @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-security, annotations, spring-annotations, spring-el

I'm using the Spring Security @PreAuthorize annotation and it works when I use "known good" expressions that I've seen in the documentation or in other online examples. The example code isn't a real use case it's contrived.

The following expressions are all variations of ones that worked on a method or methods similar in format to the example method below them. These expressions aren't being used at the same time or even the same method they're just displayed here together for simplicity.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_XYZ') or authentication.principal.id == #ownerId")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and #someValue == 'testValue'")
public List<Item> getSomeItems(Integer ownerId, String someValue ) {
    // code goes here
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is test a method argument against a session variable in the expression like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_XYZ') or #someValue == session.someOtherValue")
public List<Item> getSomeItems(Integer someValue) {
    // code goes here
}
```

I would have thought that accessing the session in an expression would be a basic task but I haven't found a single example online or even anyone asking how to do it.

I've tried all of the following and many more but they all generate exceptions:

```
@PreAuthorize("#someValue == #session.someValue")
@PreAuthorize("#someValue == session.someValue")
@PreAuthorize("#someValue == session.getAttribute('someValue')")
@PreAuthorize("#someValue == request.session.someValue")
@PreAuthorize("#someValue == request.session.getAttribute('someValue')")
```

Everything above is related to Spring Security and the @PreAuthorize annotation but those things really aren't central to question.

I'm aware of many alternatives to accessing the session and have already solved my use case but I'm still wondering if it's possible to access the session via expression in any annotation.

So... can the user session be accessed in a Spring annotation expression and if so how? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Spring Security why would you want to check a session variable instead of the currently logged in user.

Comment: I had a strong feeling that a "why would you want to do this" sentiment would pop-up almost immediately. The "userId" in the original example code isn't a real use case so it's been replaced with a more generic example showing expressions that worked. I mainly want to know if there is a simple way to access the session object or the request object via annotation expression. This is ultimately a matter of curiosity because I couldn't do something that I though would be easy.

Comment: Then you might want to use a sample which doesn't rely or resolve to the authentication. The request should be available so I would expect `request.session.getAttribute('someValue')` to actually work. Do they all generate the same exception or different ones?

Answer (score 2):

The spring EL expression for the current is `#session`.
So you could use

```
@PreAuthorize("#userId == session.userId")
```

But this session is the current HttpSession and it has no property `userId`. According to [spring el access](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/authorization.html#el-access) you can use `authentication` or `principal`

Try

```
@PreAuthorize("#userId == principal.username")
```

presuming that the username is the userId...

Comment: Are the quotes in the correct place in your first example above? Also is the syntax correct? I get a "session cannot be resolved to a variable" error in STS/Eclipse and the are no quick fixes available. I had problems with quotes in the wrong place in my original question but have fixed them. I had also tried #session without success although the syntax didn't look like yours. The question has been edited to be more general because the session value I want to test isn't related to the authentication or principle objects so I can't use principal.username.